# Prometheus dns service discovery in docker swarm

Tags: docker, dns, docker-swarm, prometheus, service-discovery

I'm searching for some monitor & alert solutions for my services. I found following nice related works.

- [Prometheus monitoring for docker swarm](https://dzone.com/articles/swarmprom-prometheus-monitoring-for-docker-swarm)
- [Monitoring a docker swarm cluster with Prometheus](https://chmod666.org/2017/08/monitoring-a-docker-swarm-cluster-with-prometheus)

Both works use dns service discovery to monitor multiple replicas of services.

I've tried to replay these work, but I found I can only get single backend container ip.

```
# dig A node-exporter

; <<>> DiG 9.10.4-P8 <<>> A node-exporter
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 18749
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;node-exporter.         IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
node-exporter.      600 IN  A   10.0.0.42

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.11#53(127.0.0.11)
;; WHEN: Mon Jan 29 02:57:51 UTC 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 60
```

When I inspect the service, I found the endpoint mode of node-exporter is vip.

```
> docker inspect 242pn4obqsly
...
"Endpoint": {
"Spec": {
    "Mode": "vip"
},
"VirtualIPs": [
    {
        "NetworkID": "61fn8hmgwg0n7rhg49ju2fdld",
        "Addr": "10.0.0.3/24"
    }
]
...
```

This means when contact with dns, prometheus can only get a single delegate service ip. Then the inner lbs strategy will route the income request to different backend instances.

Then how does the related works succeeded?

Thx!

Comment: I think I can specify the dnsrr endpoint-mode to get a client-dns service discovery. But I didn't found this settings in related works ...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For `Prometheus` DNS Service Discovery, you don't want to use `docker swarm` internal load balancing using `Virtual IP (VIP)`.

What you're looking for is a **per task** service DNS. To get IP adresses of every service in your swarm, just **prefix** the DNS of your docker swarm service name with `tasks.`.

For instance, in a swarm with 3 nodes, I get:

```
$ nslookup tasks.node-exporter
Server:    127.0.0.11
Address 1: 127.0.0.11

Name:      tasks.node-exporter
Address 1: 10.210.0.x node-exporter.xxx.mynet
Address 2: 10.210.0.y node-exporter.yyy.mynet
Address 3: 10.210.0.z node-exporter.zzz.mynet
```

But when I query the service name with no prefix, I get one IP (the VIP one that load balances requests to every container):

```
$ nslookup node-exporter
Server:    127.0.0.11
Address 1: 127.0.0.11

Name:      node-exporter
Address 1: 10.210.0.w ip-x-x-x-x
```

You can have a look at [this Q/A on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44724497/what-is-overlay-network-and-how-does-dns-resolution-work) showing 3 different way of getting a DNS resolution in `docker swarm`. Basically, for a service named `myservice` in `docker swarm`:

- `myservice` resolves to the `Virtual IP (VIP)` of that service which is internally **load balanced** to the individual task IP addresses.
- `tasks.myservice` resolves to **each Private IP** of each container deployed in the swarm.
- `docker.com` does not exist as a service name and so the request is forwarded to the configured default DNS server (that you can customize).

Note: Container names resolve as well, albeit directly to their IP addresses.

Looking at the links you provided, `node-exporter` configuration uses the `task` way of reaching services:

> Using the exporters service name, you can configure DNS discovery:
>
> ```
> scrape_configs:
> - job_name: 'node-exporter'
>   dns_sd_configs:
>   - names:
>     - 'tasks.node-exporter'
>     type: 'A'
>     port: 9100
> ```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot François. This indeeds addressed my issue. I looked into your Q/A but cannot find the comments about 'tasks.' prefix stuff. Do you know where I can find the information, i.e., some official Docker reference? Thanks

Comment: mmm... You're right, I can not find it clearly documented! Only some [github issues](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/33078) talk about that and some [blog articles](https://airtame.engineering/practical-services-monitoring-with-prometheus-and-docker-30abd3cf9603). This should definitely be better documented!

Comment: You're welcome! I did raise [this issue](https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/issues/5854) to docker documentation

Comment: Hi François, doing this results in prometheus using the ip as instance label. Is it possible to use something like node-exporter_1, node_exporter_2?

Comment: @Yannic Klem, you're right, i'm fine with that behaviour and did not try anything else, could you rise the question on another SO thread?